# Problem Using Leaflet Map In powerbi plugin

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet, powerbi

I have a problem in using leaflet  in powerbi plugin:

in the constructor, I can Show the map,mark a location on it and every thing is ok:

```
 export class Visual implements IVisual {
    private target: HTMLElement;
    private dataView: DataView;
    private map: L.Map;
    private basemap: L.TileLayer;
    private markerLayer: L.LayerGroup<L.CircleMarker>;

    constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
        console.log('constructor called');
        this.target.innerHTML='<div id="map" style="height:100vh;width:100vw;"></div>';
        this.basemap = L.tileLayer('http://localhost/mapfiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{    maxZoom: 17,minZoom:10  });

        this.map = L.map('map', {
            center: new L.LatLng(35.658, 51.403),
            zoom: 12,
            maxZoom: 18,
            minZoom: 12
        });

        this.map.addLayer(this.basemap);
    }
```

but!

In **public update**, when (for Ex.)I want to mark another location, **this.map** is Undefined!

And also, Click event returns errors about "function not found" or "MouseEvent" is not declared...

I think the exact problem is after I add the layer to the map, Leaflet loses the map reference and can't find it again for editing!

What can I do? is this a conflict between TS and JS?

[sorry for my grammar:) English is not my primary language]

Comment: May I suggest that you add all relevant code possibly in an executable snippet (either stack overflow  snippets  or code sandbox or jsfiddle or similar). It usually helps contributors to give you an answer.

Comment: Where is your `update()` method? So far can see only `constructor`.